Disable paste feature from android keyboard in OutlinedTextField using jetpack compose and kotlin
I've created a OutLinedTextField in jetpack compose, I want to disable pasting text/number into the field.
Iam able to disable the copy feature from textfield but not able to block/diable pasting in the textfield. Somehow even if a solution works on android emulator it doesn't work on samsung or other phones, as the text/number is present in clipboard thats easily available to paste from clipboard.

Why would you even want to do that? How does that increase usability? Preventing copying can povide an additional layer of security, but I fail to see how preventing pasting brings any benefits to your app.

You can refer to this answer here
